# Replicate Mass Materials [MATMAS] without Change Pointers

Tags: abap, idoc

BODS is sending millions of IDocs into SAP ECC system. In this ECC system we have a custom IDOC Extension. Only for this Extension BODS sends data.

[ BODS Sending Data ] -- (1) --> [ Source ECC ] -- (2) --> [ Target ECC ].

Problem : We want to replicate from Source ECC system to Target ECC system without Change Pointers, because these Change Pointers are causing huge delay.

How to overcome this replication without using Change Pointers?